# "Полиморфизм в иерархии классов" и "Создание иерархии классов с реализацией полиморфизма" одно и то же?

Tags: ооп

Создание иерархии классов это и есть наследование? сколько потомков должно быть? 1 или 2 достаточно??

Comment: Потомков должно быть столько, чтобы классы адекватно моделировали предметную область.

Comment: Достаточно для чего?

Answer (score 2):

1. Для демонстрации принципа ООП "Наследование" достаточно иерархии из двух классов. Например, класс В является наследником класса А и перекрывает метод print(), в котором изменяет поведение, заданное классом А.
2. Для демонстрации принципа ООП "Инкапсуляция" также достаточно двух классов. Например, в классе А есть private методы, которые не видны в классе В, и есть protected методы, которые не видны извне, но доступны в классе В.
3. Для демонстрации принципа ООП "Полиморфизм" необходимо минимум *три* класса. Например, классы В и С являются наследниками класса А. В процессе обработки мы можем объявить переменную типа класса А, даже если данный класс является абстрактным классом. В эту переменную мы можем записать объекты класса А(если он не абстрактный), В или С. И уже из этой переменной вызвать метод print(), который выведет то, что задано классом, на основании которого был создан помещенный в переменную объект. Необходимость наличия третьего класса для демонстрации принципа полиморфизма обусловлено тем, что мы можем показать в зависимости от какого класса был создан объект - зависит поведение которое будет вызвано для переменной класса А. В принципе, можно обойтись и двумя классами А и В, но это будет не так наглядно. Можно будет подумать, что работает принцип наследования, а не полиморфизм.

Что касается вопроса из топика - то он не очень корректен, так как смешиваются два понятия - принцип полиморфизма и собственно проектирование иерархии классов. Это как спросить: "Спроектировать дом" и "Нарисовать чертеж дома" это одно и то же? Вроде бы да, но по сути - нет. Так как "реализация" это не "принцип".